# What is the sinusoidal equation for this wave?

Tags: trigonometry

What is the sinusoidal equation for this wave? I don't need the exact equation, as there isn't one. I know how to solve it, but whenever I do I mess up somewhere because I keep getting 1.875 cos(π/7)+2.95 but when I graph it, it doesn't match the table.

[image: table]

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please [edit] your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Try graphing the data itself to get an estimate of the mean of the curve.  $2.95$ is way too high.

Comment: @herbsteinberg I forgot to divide 2.95 by 2, which is 1.475. That is still wrong because the equation still doesn't work

Comment: It would help if the units (degrees or radians?) that the numbers on the left are supposed to be.  The peaks seem to be about $12$ apart, but the uneven spacing makes it difficult to analyze.   As I suggested before, plot the data to get a better idea of how to start.

Comment: If you use a cosine curve, you need to include a phase shift.   The first max of the data is around $7$, not $0$ as given by $cos(\pi x/7)$.  Also your statement doesn't have a variable in the cos.

Comment: If you impose $c=\frac \pi 7$, the coefficients would be $a=1.961$ and $d=-2.163$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comments

- we do not know if the $x$ values are degrees or radians
- you need more than likely a phase shift

Anyway, in order to introduce the phase shift, I would write the model as
$$y=a+b \sin(cx)+d\cos(cx)$$ This model is nonlinear with respect to its parameters only because of $c$. If you fix $c$, the problem reduces to a simple multilinear regression. So, consider now the sum of the squares
$$SSQ(c)=\sum_{i=1}^n \left(a+b \sin(cx_i)+d\cos(cx_i)-y_i \right)^2$$

- run the linear regression for different values of $c$
- for each value of $c$, recover the value of the corresponding sum of squares
- plot $SSQ(c)$ as a function of $c$ and try to locate (more or less) a minimum
- when this will be done, you have all elements (reasonable starting guesses for $(a,b,c,d)$) to start a nonlinear regression. If you cannot use nonlinear regression, continue with the linear regression zooming more and more.
- when finished, recombine $b \sin(cx)+d\cos(cx)$ to get the phase shift.

**Edit**

I did follow the steps described above and used for $c$ a step size equal to $0.01$. Below are reproduced the results around the minimum value of $SSQ$.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 c & SSQ & a & b & d \\
 0.40 & 11.4585& 1.71838& 1.93529& -1.40612 \\
 0.41 & 8.41521& 1.79334& 1.78015& -1.71673 \\
 0.42 & 6.43999& 1.85654& 1.49990& -1.96209 \\
 0.43 & 5.50826& 1.90446& 1.13659& -2.11907 \\
 0.44 &\color{red} {5.43097}& 1.93687& 0.73446& -2.18405 \\
 0.45 & 5.97479& 1.95542&  0.32929& -2.16538 \\
 0.46 & 6.93773& 1.96229& -0.05319& -2.07640 \\
 0.47 & 8.17545& 1.95950& -0.39469& -1.93206 \\
 0.48 & 9.59722& 1.94889& -0.68194& -1.74886 \\
 0.49 & 11.1494& 1.93240& -0.90729& -1.54526 \\
 0.50 & 12.7983& 1.91225& -1.07229& -1.33913
\end{array}
\right)$$

Now, the nonlinear regression leads to $R^2=0.916515$, $SSQ=5.3744$ and the following values
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & +1.92546 & 0.26644 & \{+1.29543,+2.55549\} \\
 b & +0.90042 & 0.72962 & \{-0.82487,+2.62570\} \\
 c & +0.43593 & 0.01529 & \{+0.39977,+0.47208\} \\
 d & -2.16832 & 0.36072 & \{-3.02130,-1.31534\} \\
\end{array}$$

and we can notice that parameter $b$ is non significant.

Repeating without $b$ in the model, what is obtained is $R^2=0.900114$, $SSQ=6.4302$ and the following values
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & +1.96425 & 0.26957 & \{+1.34262,+2.58589\} \\
 c & +0.45242 & 0.00933 & \{+0.43090,+0.47393\} \\
 d & -2.14451 & 0.35010 & \{-2.95185,-1.33717\} \\
\end{array}$$